# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'stylesheet.css'

Tags: android, css, gradle

**This is My build.gradle file**

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.user.kamarado"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.6'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**when I run a project**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jg1LW.png)

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.

> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'stylesheet.css'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this in project gradle file:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'stylesheet.css'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ,but now I have this problem   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'org/osmdroid/ic_menu_mapmode.png'

Comment: add one more line pickFirst 'ic_menu_mapmode.png' and build gradle.